# Material-UI Datagrid - Replace column headers with a custom toolbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI DataGrid in my project and I need to replace all the column headers (except the checkbox column) to a toolbar. currently what I have columns like this[image: current state]:

I need to replace those columns headers with a toolbar like this, but leave the checkbox
header cell[image]

As you can see, the columns header replaced with this toolbar except the checkbox.

my columns definitions looks like this:

```
export const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: "summary",
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 110,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => <SummaryCell />,
  },
  {
    field: "accounts",
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => (
      <PossibleAccountsCell/>
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "found",
    headerName: "Found",
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => (
      <FoundSubjectsCell/>
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "inputType",
    headerName: "Progress",
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => (
      <ProgressCell/>
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "view",
    width: 245,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => (
      <ViewReportCell />
    ),
  },
];
```

My DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid
          sx={{
            "& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
              padding: 0,
            },
            "& .MuiCheckbox-root": {
              padding: 0,
            },
            "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus-within, & .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within":
              {
                outline: "none",
              },

            "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus, & .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus": {
              outline: "none",
            },
            
          }}
          autoHeight
          rows={collectionData.collections}
          columns={columns}
          paginationMode="server"
          pageSize={collectionData.collectionsPerPage}
          checkboxSelection
          disableSelectionOnClick
          rowHeight={80}
        />
```

I know I can set all the column headers to "display: none" and replace them with custom toolbar, but then I will loose the checkbox column header that I need.
Is there a way to replace them?

Answer (score 1):

One can provide a custom component for a column by providing a function for `renderHeader` like this as part of a column definition:

```
  const actionColumn = {
    field: "actions",
    type: "actions",
    renderHeader: () => (
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        size="small"
        onClick={() => navigate(`${entityUrlRoot}/new`)}
      >
        Add New
      </Button>
    ),
  };
```